# The GC args -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent cause tomcat timeout

Tags: tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm, java

These days, we encountered a strange problem, some of our solr apps on tomcat frequently timeout with large number of connections.

Several days ago, we added the gc arg -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, so we tried to remove this arg, and the number of connections declined, the timeout times declined too.

But some of our apps with this gc arg haven't encountered this problem, the difference between the sick apps and healthy apps is the jdk version. The sick apps' jdk version is 1.6.0_21, and heathy apps is 1.6.0_26.

Change the jdk version also fix the problem.

Someone can tell is this a bug of old version jdk, or bug of gc args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the use of `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` seems to be buggy with older JDK. You can take a look at [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6919638), that is resolved since 6u22 (interesting you said 6u21 fail and 6u26 works).

Comment: The bug seems like exactly what we encountered. Thx for your help.And I have anoter question, how the gc locker cause the connections of tomcat increasing.

Comment: @PeaceMaker You're welcome! For your second question I have no answer yet, I've to make research sorry. You should create a new post like that you'll get more attention. In a general way, if a new question follows from an other, writting a new post is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` all calls made by `System.gc()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` will cause long pause time. That may be the issue sick apps if healthy apps doesn't have these calls then may be you are getting issue.

I am not sure about jdk bug but may be the issue is somewhere in app.

Comment: +1 - If you've added `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` as a workaround for shoddy code that calls `System.gc()`, then the real solution is to nuke that code ... and fix whatever problem you were trying to "cure" with the `gc()` call.

Comment: @StephenC The OP is not asking what is `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent`... I guess if the user uses that option he know what it does (or he can easily google for it). What's more this answer is based on the fact that he removed the option, but clearely the pb occurs WITH the option : "But some of our apps `with` this gc arg haven't encountered this problem".

Comment: @alain.janinm is right, the problem occurs when we add this gc arg, not when we remove it.

Comment: I cannot speak for the OP, but Tomcat causes hourly GC calls.  See https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53267   Some attempt to work around this Tomcat bug by using -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent.  See, for example,  http://markmail.org/message/w7nrxstaljhgwryv